# How to get only one value in SSRS?

Tags: ssrs-2016

[image]

This is the values in table1.
[image]

I have a data in a Table1 where it is login hours for a day for multiple employees. I am creating a SSRS report and data they want is below
This is the Output i need in the below table in SSRS 2016.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Create row group and group by time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looking to hide repeating "time" value, then you can use expression for that column:

```
=IIF(Fields!time.Value = Previous(Fields!time.Value), "", Fields!time.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was breaking ,my head over this for  a long time.

Comment: No problem, any time