# SSRS grouping all but one field

Tags: grouping, ssrs-2016

I have a query that all the fields are the same except for one.  I want to group my SSRS report so that it has "blanks" for all the duplicated fields and only show the "different" one WHEN there is a "duplicate" record.

```
For instance:
Case Number  PersonID   Narrative
123            1        xxx
345            3
456            9         ABCD
                         KFL
```

So record 1 has a narrative and only one record.  Record 2 has no narrative.  Record 3 & 4 are the same case, same person, two different narratives.

I thought by grouping by all the other fields that I would achieve these results but that is not working, I still get the 456 and 9 on my 4th record when I have grouped by the other fields.

How can I get just the narrative to display when all the other fields in that record match the previous record?

Thanks,
Leslie

Comment: probably need to see the dataset output but my guess would be to group by case number and personid and have narrative in hte detail 'group'

Comment: Thanks Alan, that's what I thought too, that's what I did and it didn't work which is why I posted the question.

Comment: Can you post some sample data to produce your sample output, I'll then try to replicate it.

Comment: Andrey's solution did what I needed.  Thanks.

Comment: OK Great, if this is a table rather than a matrix you can also just set the "HideDuplicates" property of the cell(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can see my answer for:
[How to get only one value in SSRS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289309/how-to-get-only-one-value-in-ssrs)

You have similar situation. You need to use expression for first 2 columns:

```
=IIF(Fields!CaseNumber.Value = Previous(Fields!CaseNumber.Value), "", Fields!CaseNumber.Value)

=IIF(Fields!PersonID.Value = Previous(Fields!PersonID.Value), "", Fields!PersonID.Value)
```

This will hide all repeating "Case Number" and "PersonID".

Don't forget to replace "CaseNumber" and "PersonID" with proper column names in DataSet.